# Global Query Data

Tags: php, codeigniter

There's a part of a code (query) that will be required in all controllers, they will be passed into views for display.

Can I know is there anyway to declare them in just a single file so that I can reference them directly from my view? Without declaring them in each controller's _construct.

I'm using codeigniter3, here's a sample code:

MainController.php

```
public function index(){
      $data['userCampaign'] = $this->Usermodel->getCampaign();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create default controller in your project which extends `CI_Controller` and your `all controller` extends `new controller` and in `__construct();` function of your `new controller` you can add this code.

Comment: You mean create a default controller and then put the query in it's _constructor() function, then my MainController would extend this default controller? But I will need to use the code in each controllers too right? I'm quite confused...

Comment: No, as you add this code to common controller `__construct();` function it will be available in all controller

Comment: @KarlWong have you test ?

Comment: I've found another solution which is creating a helper but your solution would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Declare this function as `protected` in parent controller class.

Comment: My main class extends CI_Controller, so you mean i need to declare it in the core files?

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't know there is method like that.

> You want call the function in `__construct()` or you have to declare function in controller and call it back. `$this->check_session()`

Comment: So there's no global file which I can autoload and then reference them without the controller? I mean I want a variable...which is obtained through a query.

Comment: No. have to do it manually. And  read this too [Where to place global functions in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831213/where-to-place-global-functions-in-codeigniter)

Comment: and read this too (CodeIgniter global function)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237112/code-igniter-global-function]